# Automapper: Access member information in custom converter

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, automapper

I wrote my custom converter to map between classes, but although the types are all the same for all attributes, some of my attributes need a special treatment.

So I would like to access the name of the property, what is currently mapped. There used to be a property "memberName" in the ResolutionContext, but it is not here anymore. 
I could also decorate every attribute or pass information about every attribute in the Map-function itself.

What is the recommended way in this case?

```
public class IntToTermsetConverter : ITypeConverter<List<GenericHistory<Term>>, List<GenericHistory<int?>>>
{
    ITermsetService termsetService;
    public IntToTermsetConverter()
    {
        this.termsetService = new TermsetService(new TermsetRepository(new UnitOfWork()));
    }
    public List<GenericHistory<int?>> Convert(List<GenericHistory<Term>> genHis, List<GenericHistory<int?>> genTarget, ResolutionContext context)
    {
//Need some information about the currently mapped attribute - for example the name or something else I could pass
        if (genHis != null)
            return termsetService.FromTermToIndex(genHis, (string)context.Options.Items["termsetName"]);
        else
            return null;
    }
}
```